# Bottomsheet in Fragment throwing null pointer exception

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, fragment

I am using Tablayout with Viewpager. I have tried calling the bottomsheetbehavior in OnCreateview also but it didn't work. Does bottomsheet only work with the activities? What I have to do in order to get bottomsheet working. I am working on this problem from past two hours and have searched for the solution but couldn't find any solution.

**FragmentConv.kt**

**Updated**

```
class FragmentConversation : Fragment() {

    lateinit var conversationAdapter: ConversationAdapter
    lateinit var list: ArrayList<TestingModel>
    lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<RelativeLayout>
    lateinit var listmodel2:ArrayList<TestingModel2>
    lateinit var  languageAdapter: LanguageAdapter
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false)
        Log.d("FragmentConverssation", "onCreateView: OnCreateView Called of Conversation")
        val recylerview = v.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recylerviewConvo)

        bottomSheetBehavior=BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)


        //#3 Listening to State Changes of BottomSheet
//        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
//            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
////                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
////                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED;
////                }
//            }
//
//            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
//
//            }

//        })

//        val sender_btn=v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.sender_btn)
//        val receiver_btn=v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.receiver_btn)
//
//        sender_btn.setOnClickListener {
//
//            list.add(TestingModel("sender","From sender"))
//
//            conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
//            recylerview.smoothScrollToPosition(recylerview.bottom)
//        }



        recylerview.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        recylerview.hasFixedSize()



        conversationAdapter = ConversationAdapter(createModel(), requireContext())

        recylerview.adapter=conversationAdapter

        bottomSheetEvents()


        return v
    }


    fun createModel(): ArrayList<TestingModel> {


        list = ArrayList()
        list.add(TestingModel("sender", "Hi How are you"))
        list.add(TestingModel("receiver", "I am fine"))
        list.add(TestingModel("sender", "What's going on"))


        return list


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    fun bottomSheetEvents(){

        val recyclerView=bottomSheet.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recylerviewlang)
        recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize()

        listmodel2= ArrayList()
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))
        listmodel2.add(TestingModel2("Urdu","ur"))

        languageAdapter= LanguageAdapter(listmodel2,requireContext())

        recyclerView.adapter=languageAdapter



    }
}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">





<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recylerviewConvo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/language_bottomsheet"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet1"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**bottomsheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    android:elevation="20sp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Languages"
        android:id="@+id/textlang"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylerviewlang"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**StackTrace** **Updated**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.googletranslator, PID: 6719
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.from(BottomSheetBehavior.java:1632)
        at com.example.googletranslator.Fragments.FragmentConversation.onCreateView(FragmentConversation.kt:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1816)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:238)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved it by excluding the include tag from my fragment layout. Then I directly used bottomsheet layout xml as a child of Coordinator layout.

Answer (score 0):

`bottomSheetBehavior` is null in `onCreateView()`, because you are initialising it in `onViewCreated()`, which is called after `onCreateView()`.

Either create `bottomSheetBehavior` earlier or call `bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback` later, after creation of `bottomSheetBehavior`.

Update: `bottomSheet` object is null in `BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)`.

Comment: I have mentioned that in the question that I have also tried to call it in the onCreateView

Comment: `bottomSheet` object is null in `BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)`. I don't see initialisation anywhere

Comment: its the id of bottomsheetlayout. You can check it in bottomsheet.xml file

Comment: You're inflating `fragment_conversation`, but in the post you write `fragment.xml`. Are you sure it's the correct layout file?
Are you sure you don't need to find bottomSheet? `bottomSheet = v.findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet)`

Comment: yes its the same layout file. I have just used a random name here. I don't think we have to do bottomsheet=v.findviewById(R.id.bottomsheet) whilte usinf the bottomsheet.,